How AWS DMS handle Encryption during DB2 LUW to Aurora PostgreSQL migration
I'm doing Migration from DB2 LUW to Aurora PostgreSQL using AWS DMS.
Source DB2 LUW side, inserted data to below column with ENCRYPT scalar function.
PASSWORD CHARACTER(48) FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL,
How AWS DMS handle encrypted data during migration, what all encryption settings we need to set.
I directly run the migration task and can see the data in target.
When trying to decrypt the data getting error.
That means the data has not been migrated properly.
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;  -- this is already done
Errors:
[Code: 0, SQL State: 42883]  ERROR: function pgp_sym_decrypt(bytea, unknown) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 20  [Script position: 272 - 314]
Sometimes will see wrong key or corrupt data error

I suspect that you are expected to decrypt the column BEFORE export, and then re-encrypt on the target with whatever algorithms are available on the target. I would not expect migration from one RDBMS engine to a different engine from a different supplier to be able to handle encrypted data.

Do we have any settings for encryption in AWS DMS?

Use the postgresql pgcrypto extension module to perform the column encryption on the target.
